# Android client broadcast UDP request for server IP receive echo instead of answer

Tags: android, c++, udp, arduino-ide, esp32

I have an embedded system (ESP32) that can alter from wifi client to wifi Access Point with a toggle switch and have the ability to communicate through TCP with an Android app to control relays and stuff. I started the project with it working as an AP and the whole project was working fine. My problem is that when I implemented UDP discovery for it to work in every network I wanted my ESP32 to receive the UDP request and initiates the TCP comms, but my app only gets my request message (echo) as a response. Please point me towards the reason for this and how to fix it.

I used [this answer](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=568141.0) that pointed to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3vOyzJzGRU) to try and code the UDP message exchange.

Also, I'm using [this GitHub library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32) with [this implementation of UDP comms](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiUdp.cpp). I tried [this one](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/AsyncUDP/src/AsyncUDP.cpp) before, and it didn't work, so I changed it hoping it would solve. In both libraries, I've found little information on the client + server message exchange and no examples in UDP discovery.

First code part is the minimal function of my application that will fire the UDP request. The first condition function says that my device is connected to a wifi network:

```
if (wifiTest.haveNetworkConnection((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))){
    try {
        UDP_DiscoverServer discoverServer = new UDP_DiscoverServer();
        ipDescoberto = discoverServer.execute(Tela_Selecao_Bancada.this, "Se4rch_f0r_coNnect1on_with_server_Device\r\n").get(); //this line is supposed to give back my embedded devide ip string
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (ipDescoberto != null){
        /*  .
            .
        Some code
            .
            .   */
    } else {
        final  String failedText = "No device connection detected. Check if your phone and device share the same network.";
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), failedText, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Now, still in my application, this is my private AsyncTask that will run the UDP request and return my response:

```
private static class UDP_DiscoverServer extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    private Inet4Address ipAddress;
    private int port;
    private String resp = null;
    private DatagramSocket datagramSocket;
    private WeakReference<Tela_Selecao_Bancada> activity;


    public UDP_DiscoverServer() {
        super();
        this.ipAddress = getBroadcast();
        this.port = 39600;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... args) {
        activity = new WeakReference<>((Tela_Selecao_Bancada) args[0]);
        String mensagem = (String) args[1];
        try {
            datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
            datagramSocket.setBroadcast(true);
            String CRLF = "\r\n";
            if (!mensagem.endsWith(CRLF)) {
                mensagem += CRLF;
            }
            DatagramPacket packetSend = new DatagramPacket(mensagem.getBytes(), mensagem.length(), ipAddress, port);
            datagramSocket.send(packetSend);
            datagramSocket.setReceiveBufferSize(1024);
            byte[] respBuffer = new byte[100];
            DatagramPacket packetReceive = new DatagramPacket(respBuffer, respBuffer.length);
            datagramSocket.receive(packetReceive);

            resp = new String(packetReceive.getData(), 0, packetReceive.getLength()); 
            if (resp.length() > 10 && resp.startsWith("Hell0_client")) //this line shows the debbug result
                return resp;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO: For DEBUG purpose only. Comment the following line before publishing the app
            Log.d("erroPeerConn", "error trying to discover connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Snackbar.make(activity.get().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Error trying to send broadcast. Check your WiFi connection.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        datagramSocket.close();
        if (activity != null) activity.clear();
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    private Inet4Address getBroadcast(){
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> niEnum = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (niEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface ni = niEnum.nextElement();
                if (!ni.isLoopback()) {
                    if (!ni.getInterfaceAddresses().isEmpty()) {
                        InterfaceAddress interfaceAddress = ni.getInterfaceAddresses().get(0);
                        return (Inet4Address) Inet4Address.getByName(interfaceAddress.getBroadcast().toString().substring(1));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException | UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally this is my ESP32 minimal "code". Acctually it's just a machine state function that will be excecuted repeatedly until a client shows up (make an UDP request):

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

#define PORT_DISCOVER     39600

const char *MENSAGEM_DISCOVER = "Se4rch_f0r_coNnect1on_with_server_Device\r\n";
WiFiUDP serverDiscover;
WiFiClient client;
IPAddress clientTCP_IP;

boolean broadcastListening(){
  if (!listeningUmaVez){
    serverDiscover.begin(PORT_DISCOVER);
    listeningUmaVez = true;
    Serial.print("UDP Listening on Port: ");
    Serial.println(PORT_DISCOVER);
  }
  if (!client){
    //processing incoming packet, must be called before reading the buffer
    serverDiscover.parsePacket();
    //receive response from client
    char readBuffer[100] = '\0';
    int readLength = serverDiscover.read(readBuffer, 100);
    if(readLength > 0){
      Serial.print("Cliente Android para ESP: ");
      Serial.println(*&readBuffer);
      if (strcmp(MENSAGEM_DISCOVER, *&readBuffer) == 0){
        Serial.println("Conexão detectada:");
        Serial.print("From: ");
        Serial.print(serverDicover.remoteIP());
        clientTCP_IP = serverDicover.remoteIP();
        Serial.print(":");
        Serial.print(serverDicover.remotePort());
        Serial.print(", Length: ");
        Serial.print(packet.length());
        Serial.println();
        //reply to the client
        serverDiscover.beginPacket(clientTCP_IP, PORT_DISCOVER);
        char auxChar[50] = "Hell0_client_4ndr0id.This_1s_My_IP_";
        strcat(auxChar, IPAddressToCharArray(lastConnectionType == HIGH?WiFi.localIP():WiFi.softAPIP())); // lastConnectionType is an input that says if it is an AP or Station.
        Serial.print("Response string: ");
        Serial.println(*&auxChar);
        serverDiscover.write((const uint8_t*)*&auxChar, strlen(auxChar));
        serverDiscover.endPacket();
        //serverDiscover.stop();
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is the Android Studio debbug variables at the showed up above code line:

```
mensagem = "Se4rch_f0r_coNnect1on_with_server_Device\r\n"
CRLF = "\r\n"
datagramSend = {DatagramPacket@4719} 
respBuffer = {byte[100]@4721} 
datagramReceive = {DatagramPacket@4722} 
resp = "Se4rch_f0r_coNnect1on_with_server_Device\r\n"
```

Comment: You are receiving your own broadcast. You need to disable loopback, or ignore datagrams sourced from your own host.

Comment: Well, I haven't thought about it, but you might be right! I'll try it out and then get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @user207421, you were right, it worked! I just need a few adjustments in my server and client sides for it to be a reliable communication. If you want to make an answer to my question, I'll be glad to accept it. Thank you so much!